# Bug with registering email after asking question

Tags: bug

I asked a question on writers.stackexchange.

I chose a name, 'studymate', and wrote in my email. This was an authentic email I used. The following day, I went to edit my question. Alas, I could not.

I went to my email because I was sent a registration message. I clicked it. It said registration successful without me doing anything. This was because I was logged into to my other stack exchange account (I didn't log in the first time I asked the question).

Because of this, the question I asked on an account that I used my email with is not on my profile.

The solution to this would be to **not accept emails already used**. I registered 'studymate' with an email I use for other stackexchange account, so it was already registered and the question I ask did not get transferred across.

Comment: You can merge profiles by contacting Stack Exchange with the `contact us` link in the footer of every page - it'll normally be done within a day.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Ok thank you I will do that now. I still think emails should be accepted if they are unique only.